# Running an oracle (written in node.js) after compile/migrate contracts

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I'm trying to write some tests for truffle, but I've realized that when running `truffle test`, before the test file is executed, truffle performs the compilation and migration of the contracts. For this reason, I need my [oracle](https://blockchainhub.net/blockchain-oracles/) to be launched just after the migration because when launched it is waiting for events coming from a specific contract address.

Is there any way of launching the oracle programmatically and keeping it alive during the test? The command to launch it is simple, just something like `node oracle.js --network=test`

I guess my code is not needed for the question, but anyway, if you need to know any approach I'm following on the project feel free to ask about.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to launch the oracle from any `.js` test file that requires the oracle to be running. You could likely accomplish this using a `npm` package such as [`forever`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for